# How do you sort a parent collection and child collection of entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Is there any way to sort both an inlcuded child collection and the parent collection?  I am using LINQ to Entities and EF 5.0.

Here is my query which does not work.  If I take out the OrderBy in the Include, it works just fine except that the child list is not sorted.

```
return (from parent in m_Context.Parents
            .Include(p => p.Children.OrderBy(c => c.ChildInformation.Name).Select(c => c.ChildInformation)
        orderby parent.Name
        select parent)
        .ToList();
```

For example, the collection:

- P2

  - C3
  - C1
  - C2
- P1

  - C2
  - C1

should be returned as...

- P1

  - C1
  - C2
- P2

  - C1
  - C2
  - C3

but the best I can do now is...

- P1

  - C2
  - C1
- P2

  - C3
  - C1
  - C2

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort inner collection (because you can't assign result of sorting to `parent.Children` property), but you can return anonymous objects with sorted parents and sorted children without including children in parent entity:

```
return (from parent in m_Context.Parents
        orderby parent.Name
        select new {
           Parent = parent,
           Children = parent.Children.OrderBy(c => c.ChildInformation.Name)
        }).ToList();
```

Or retrieve parents and sort children in memory.